# Constant request for CAPTCHA verification

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Every answer I post is asking me to do a CAPTCHA verification. This is very much frustrating.

I have been in stackexchange network for quite a while.

Does this happens to the beta sites?

Comment: Just did it posting this question too...

Comment: Seems to be related to my Chrome filters. Once turned off for the site, problems went away... I must have done that ages ago for the other Stack sites I'm on.

Comment: What filter was that? I need that info to reproduce the bug.

Comment: @Sklivvz - Seems it may have been Better Popup Blocker.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking/answering/editing a lot of things in a row, it tends to up the number of times you get a CAPTCHA. I don't know the rate at which you are posting things, but that might be part of the problem.

From a [Meta.SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/how-often-do-captchas-appear):

> > trigger CAPTCHA while editing, asking, or answering:
>
> The minimum window is 5 seconds The maximum window is 40 minutes There
>   is a maximum of:
>
> one edit every 30 seconds one answer every 60 seconds one question
>   every 60 seconds To trigger CAPTCHA while doing performing other
>   actions, there are throttles of various sizes depending on the action
>   -- it's mostly a "slow down" speed bump to inhibit potentially dangerous "I'm going to post obscene things as fast as possible!"
>   situations.

Comment: I haven't been that fast...

Comment: Hmm...I don't know then, unfortunately - all of my meta.SO research leads to a question of speed. :(

Comment: Seems to have settled down... I don't normally see that kind of thing happening, but maybe there was a pattern to it.

Comment: Or it was just a temporary bug that fixed itself. :)